# Encontrando strings em um log e outros padrões

Tags: python, regex

Estou tentando identificar duas strings em um arquivo de log: "connected" e "disconnected". Mas não tenho certeza de como fazer funcionar isso.

Em meu servidor tenho armazenados vários arquivos de log

```
import os
import time
import re

data = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

logs = []

#listar os arquivos .LOGS
for file in os.listdir('/var/log/mikrotik'):
 if file.endswith(".log"):
  if(re.search(data,file)): 
   logs.append(os.path.join("/var/log/mikrotik", file))

for l in logs:
 file=open(l,"r")
 for line in file.read():
  if re.match("/connected|disconnected/",line):
   print line
  else:
   print line
```

O que eu estou tentando fazer, eu verifico todos meus .logs que possuem a data atual. e armazeno eles em uma lista, para depois tentar tratar cada log individualmente tentando identificar as linhas que possuem "connected" e "disconnected", se eu encontrar em preciso apenas pegar o "user" e a data e hora dessas linha, porém não tenho ideia de como isso pode ser. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Log:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/264159/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o código.

Comment: Editado e postado o código.

Comment: Shell script atende ide maneira muito simples isso. Por que não usar então?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei esse solução:

```
import os
import re
import sys

f = open('log.log','r')
log = []
for line in f:
 if re.search(r': connected|: disconnected',line):
  ob = dict()
  ob['USER'] = re.search(r'<pppoe(.*?)>',line).group(0).replace("<pppoe-","").replace(">","")
  ob['DATA'] = re.search(r'^\w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',line).group(0)
  ob['CONNECTION'] = re.search(r': .*',line).group(0).replace(": ", "")
  log.append(ob)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
file=open(l,"r")
    for line in file.readline():
        if 'connected' in line or 'disconnected' in line:
            #capture line
            #filtre para obter o usuário, data e hora
            print line
...
```